# can I go to a new section after submitting a form in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My template is composed by section and div tags, and

I want to know is there a way make me go to a new section

```
<section> </section>
```

on the same template-page `only when my form is submitted` , if yes, how i can force that on html template what i should put as a condition before the section tag because i want in the same way display error message and go to the first page if the form is not submitted!!.

**----i have tried to do that by the submitting button where i have set the "id" tag of the next section where should go after the submitting button but it just goes to First page not to the specific id section that i have set it on the button tag.-----**

```
  <button onclick="location.href='#registration'">Submit</button>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#registration"><button>submit</button></a>
```

You may have to add a few things to make it work exactly like you want.

However note that this is not a django question, rather an html question.

Comment: thanks @RandomMadi  i have already tried that , the same result always scroll on the top of the page browser....